# App RunTime Crash - Unfortunately Stopped

Tags: java, debugging, crash, runtime, logcat

My MainScreen contain 4 ImageViews, every ImageView will send the user to category activity, then Send Extra data to show content in a ListView, but once I click on any ImageView the app stops working, and shows me this error message in the Logcat.
Anyone know what this mean ?

> Blockquote
>   04-13 21:43:53.337 15929-15929/com.ibuilder.the50recipes E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                              Process: com.ibuilder.the50recipes, PID: 15929
>                                                                              java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 25600012 byte allocation with 9652808 free bytes and 9MB until OOM
>                                                                                  at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:620)
>                                                                                  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:455)
>                                                                                  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1152)
>                                                                                  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:855)
>                                                                                  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:706)
>                                                                                  at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:776)
>                                                                                  at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:530)
>                                                                                  at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:351)
>                                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:200)
>                                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
>                                                                                  at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
>                                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:85)
>                                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:94)
>                                                                                  at com.ibuilder.the50recipes.Category_New$CustomAdapter.getView(Category_New.java:659)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2406)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1975)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:709)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:770)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1749)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2205)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17564)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5654)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1730)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1496)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17564)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5654)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17564)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5654)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17564)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5654)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17564)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5654)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17564)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5654)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17564)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5654)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:725)
>                                                                                  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17564)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5654)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2406)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2126)
>   04-13 21:43:53.337 15929-15929/com.ibuilder.the50recipes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1286)
>                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6536)
>                                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
>                                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
>                                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
>                                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6247)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's trying to allocate 25 mb of memory when it only has 9 mb until out of memory.

You'll probably need to read up on how to load large bitmaps more efficiently:

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html

From there it says how you can load a resource efficiently:

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and optimise your image by using https://tinypng.com/. Your image resource is too large.